# Android: Configurations .xml must agree on the root element's ID

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My app used to compile successfully, but it suddenly produces an error message when compiling:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.
> Configurations for item_list.xml must agree on the root element's ID.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have two layouts for item_list and item_list(landscape) and did not modify any of these files.
I use Android 4.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have two layouts, you already have changed them, as you are not using the framework's default. The error message means, that these two versions of the same layout have two different IDs on their root node. To fix that, just use an identical ID on both of the root nodes.

Comment: It works. However, it is weird as it was OK for several builds before.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have an `<include>` (like in Master/Detail Flow) and in one xml file I have only a RecyclerView and in the other (for 900dp screen wide) I have the RecyclerView inside a LinearLayout? The two RecyclerView must have the same id...

Comment: is there any way to disable viewBinding for these layouts? I have already tried tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"

Answer (score 1):

Just add a LinearLayout each an every layout file i.e Landscape, portrait. No need to declare Id on root element.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make more than one layout with the same name, give the same root id to both of them.

ex.

```xml
activity_main.xml(normal xml){    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main/">
        }
     activity_main.xml(large xml) {    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main/">
        }
```