# Configurations for foo.xml must agree on the root element's ID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-navigation

My problem is exactly the same as the one described here:
[Android: Configurations .xml must agree on the root element's ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864197/android-configurations-xml-must-agree-on-the-root-elements-id)

and I understand the solution to the question.
However, what I can't understand is **why the same layout files work without errors in another project** I copied them from (namely, the source project is [Android Navigation codelab](https://github.com/android/codelab-android-navigation) downloaded from [Learn Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#0) official codelab).

The issue is this: the layout file `navigation_activity.xml` has a base file and 2 configuration versions for Screen Width and Screen Height qualifiers.
The root element for the base file is a `DrawerLayout` with id "@+id/drawer_layout" whilst the configuration versions have a `LinearLayout` and a `RelativeLayout` root elements, respectively, without `id`.
Both projects use the same SDK 34, same build tool Kotlin DSL, same versions.